# How to find the percentage after taking the count using summarise

Tags: r, dplyr

let's say I have this data set :

```
footballplayers    Nationality      
A                   Germany
B                   Germany             
C                   France
D                   France
E                   Belgium
F                   Belgium
```

I took the count :

```
df %>% group_by(Nationality) %>% summarise(count=n())

Nationality     count 
Germany         2
France          2               
Belgium         2
```

now I have to find the percentage of each nationality: 2/6 *100 for example in this case. so how to do it in a single query after taking the count? so that I can use it in the pie chart.

Comment: You can perhaps do `df %>%
 count(Nationality) %>%
 mutate(n = n/sum(n) * 100)`.

Comment: thanks, it worked but can we do it using summarise and groupby?

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
df %>% 
group_by(Nationality) %>% 
summarise(Count = n()) %>% 
mutate(percentage = round(Count / sum(Count) * 100, 2))
```

You can omit the round function if you do not want to round the percentage!

Comment: thank you! i have another issue i am trying to plot pie chart but the percent is not displaying properly on the pie chart i have 10 nationality and i want to display the percentage of each nationality on the pie chart. what i did is fifa_data %>% count(Nationality) %>% mutate(n=n/sum(n)) %>% ggplot( aes(x="", y=n, fill=Nationality))+
geom_bar(width = 1, stat = "identity") +  coord_polar("y", start=0)+ 
  
  geom_text(aes(y = n , 
                label = percent(n)), size=3)